# How to catch exceptions from multiple threads?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, exception, python-multithreading

I have a set of functions I would like to execute in threads. Some of these functions may raise a specific exception I would like to catch, separately for each thread.

I tried something along the lines of

```py
import threading

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def fun():
    raise MyException

myfuns = [threading.Thread(target=fun), threading.Thread(target=fun)]
for myfun in myfuns:
    try:
        myfun.start()
    except MyException:
        print("caught MyException")
```

I expected to see `caught MyException` twice, one for each thread. But there is only one.

Is it possible to catch exceptions in threads independently of each other? (in other words: when a thread raises an exception, manage it in the code that called the thread?)

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: @Woj: Is [threading.excepthook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.excepthook) sufficient ?

Comment: Are you early enough in design/implementation to refactor with concurrent.futures?

Comment: @wwii: Python 3.8. I am at the design phase. My current (amateur/home) code calls the functions sequentially and I would like to thread them. I do not know concurrent.futures so I will read the docs to understand how this could help

Comment: @MauriceMeyer: that could be a very interesting solution - I will read the details and try that out, thank you.

Comment: If you succeed with an implementation, consider [Answering your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 6):

For Python 3.8+ you can define a handler for uncaught exceptions.

```
import threading

def f(args):
    print(f'caught {args.exc_type} with value {args.exc_value} in thread {args.thread}\n')
    
threading.excepthook = f

class MyException(Exception):
    pass

def fun():
    raise MyException

myfuns = [threading.Thread(target=fun), threading.Thread(target=fun)]
for myfun in myfuns:
    myfun.start()
for myfun in myfuns:
    myfun.join()
```

Comment: Thank you - it seems that your other proposal with `concurrent.futures` has my exact problem as an example: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example